# How to change text on form submit page based on radio button select?

Tags: php, html, forms

On "form.html", I have a basic HTML form:

```html
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
  <input type="radio" name="SQ1" value="y"> Yes<br>
  <input type="radio" name="SQ1" value="n"> No<br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

On "submit.php", I have a table. I am trying to change the text inside the table based on what radio button is selected.

```html
<table id="results">
 <tr>
  <th>h1</th>
  <th>h2</th>
  <th>h3</th>
  <th>h4</th>
  <th>h5</th>
  <th>h6</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><?php
            $sq1 = $_POST["sq1"];
            if ($sq1 = y) {
                echo "0";
            }
            else {
                echo "1";
            }
        ?></td>
  <td><?php
            $sq1 = $_POST["sq1"];
            if ($sq1 = y) {
                echo "0";
            }
            else {
                echo "1";
            }
        ?></td>
  <td><?php
            $sq1 = $_POST["sq1"];
            if ($sq1 = y) {
                echo "1";
            }
            else {
                echo "0";
            }
        ?></td>
        <td><?php
            $sq1 = $_POST["sq1"];
            if ($sq1 = y) {
                echo "1";
            }
            else {
                echo "0";
            }
        ?></td>
                <td><?php
            $sq1 = $_POST["sq1"];
            if ($sq1 = y) {
                echo "1";
            }
            else {
                echo "0";
            }
        ?></td>
                <td><?php
            $sq1 = $_POST["sq1"];
            if ($sq1 = y) {
                echo "1";
            }
            else {
                echo "0";
            }
        ?></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

No matter what button is selected, the data appears as if $sq1 = y.

Comment: One equals doesn't compare it assigns. Use `==`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @chris85 That seemed to work, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with your if statement condition, 
1) if($sq1=y) will return true it is assignment operation

2) y is string use the double quotation "y".

3) to compare string use == or strcmp($var1,$var2) which returns 0 in case of equal strings